# How to convert horizontal bounding box coordinates to oriented bounding box coordinates

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am trying to detect oriented bounding boxes with faster rcnn for a long time, but I could not make it to do so. I aim to detect objects in the DOTA dataset. I was using built-in faster rcnn model in pytorch, but realized that it does not support OBB. Then I found another library named detectron2 that is built on the pytorch framework. Built-in faster rcnn network in detectron2 is actually compatible with OBB but I could not make that model work with DOTA. Because I could not convert DOTA box annotations to `(cx, cy, w, h, a)`. In DOTA, objects are annotated by coordinates of 4 corners which are `(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)`.

I can't come up with a solution that converts these 4 coordinates to `(cx, cy, w, h, a)`, where `cx` and `cy` are the center point of OBB and `w`, `h`, and `a` are width, height and angle respectively.

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rectangle is as below (easily adjusted if otherwise)

[image: rectangle]

Then:

1. The tangent of the angle of rotation is given by

$tan(a)=\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}$

Depending on quadrant of interest one can take the opposite coordinates. Getting the inverse tan function gives the angle in radians.

2. The width is given by

$w=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

Similar for height

3. The center x is given by

$cx=\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}$

And similar for cy. Rotation is assumed to leave center unaffected.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I am surprised how simple these formulas are. Struggling too much prevents seeing simple solutions I think.

Comment: Your assumption is right. The location of the center point is not affected by the rotation angle of the rectangle.

Comment: Glad it helped. Visualizing the shape makes it easier.

Comment: Well, what if the starting point of the coordinates of the rectangle is not always started from the top left corner but from random corner and I always want to calculate the positive angle of the rectangle w.r.t x axis? How can you pick proper coordinates to calculate angle?

Comment: You can check the coordinates, which is larger in adjacent corners and adjust the formulas given above.

Comment: I think step 3 (in above answer by Nikos M.) should be... *The center x is given by*: $ cx = \frac{x_1 + x_3}{2} $